# Parallelise output of input function in Snakemake

Tags: python, function, lambda, wildcard, snakemake

Hello Snakemake community,

I am having quite some troubles to define correctly a **function** in Snakemake and call it in the **params** section. The output of the function is a list and my aim is to use each item of the list as a parameter of a shell command. In other words, I would like to run **multiple jobs in parallel** of the same shell command with a different parameter.

This is the function:

```
import os, glob
def get_scontigs_names(wildcards):
   scontigs = glob.glob(os.path.join("reference", "Supercontig*"))
   files = [os.path.basename(s) for s in scontigs]
   return name
```

The output is a list that looks like:

`['Supercontig0', 'Supercontig100', 'Supercontig2', ...]`

The Snakemake rules are:

```
rule all:
    input:
        "updated/all_supercontigs.sorted.vcf.gz"
rule update_vcf:
    input:
        len="genome/genome_contigs_len_cumsum.txt",
        vcf="filtered/all.vcf.gz"
    output:
        cat="updated/all_supercontigs.updated.list"
    params:
        scaf=get_scontigs_names
    shell:
        """
        python 3.7 scripts/update_genomic_reg.py -len {input.len} -vcf {input.vcf} -scaf {params.scaf}
        ls updated/*.updated.vcf.gz > {output.cat}
        """
```

This code is incorrect because all the items of the list are loaded into the shell command when I call `{params.scaf}`. The current shell commands looks like:

`python 3.7 scripts/update_genomic_reg.py -len genome/genome_contigs_len_cumsum.txt -vcf filtered/all.vcf.gz -scaf Supercontig0 Supercontig100 Supercontig2 ...`

**What I would like to get is:***

`python 3.7 scripts/update_genomic_reg.py -len genome/genome_contigs_len_cumsum.txt -vcf filtered/all.vcf.gz -scaf Supercontig0`

`python 3.7 scripts/update_genomic_reg.py -len genome/genome_contigs_len_cumsum.txt -vcf filtered/all.vcf.gz -scaf Supercontig100`

and so on.

I have tried to use `wildcards` inside the function but I am failing to give it the correct attribute.

There are several posts about input functions and wildcards plus the snakemake docs but I could not really apply them to my case.
Can somebody help me with this, please?

Comment: have you considered `xargs` or `parallel` to run multiple jobs within a rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my question inspired by @dariober.

```
rule all:
input:
    "updated/all_supercontigs.updated.list"

import os, glob

def get_scontigs_names(wildcards):
    scontigs = glob.glob(os.path.join("reference", "Supercontig*"))
    files = [os.path.basename(s) for s in scontigs]
    name = [i.split('_')[0] for i in files]
    return name

rule update_vcf:
    input:
        len="genome/genome_contigs_len_cumsum.txt",
        vcf="filtered/all.vcf.gz"
    output:
        vcf="updated/all_{supercontig}.updated.vcf.gz"
    params:
        py3=config["modules"]["py3"],
        scaf=get_scontigs_names
    shell:
        """
        {params.py3} scripts/update_genomic_reg.py -len {input.len} -vcf 
        {input.vcf} -scaf {wildcards.supercontig}
        """


rule list_updated:
    input:
        expand("updated/all_{supercontig}.updated.vcf.gz", supercontig = 
        supercontigs)
    output:
        "updated/all_supercontigs.updated.list"
    shell:
        """
        ls {input} > {output}
        """
```

Comment: Good you found a solution. But I still don't get the point of having `get_scontigs_names ` as an input function in the rule since its output doesn't depend on the wildcards. Personally, I find this makes to code a bit contrived but I may be wrong. (Also, for readability I would put the `import` statements at the top of the script)

Comment: I have not really understood how to use `wildcards` inside the input function. Does anyone have a very simple and clear example of such a function?

Answer (score 1):

What about this below? Note that your `get_scontigs_names` doesn't make use of wildcards.

```
import os, glob

def get_scontigs_names():
   scontigs = glob.glob(os.path.join("reference", "Supercontig*"))
   files = [os.path.basename(s) for s in scontigs]
   name = [i.split('_')[0] for i in files]
   return name

supercontigs= get_scontigs_names()

rule all:
    input:
        "updated/all_supercontigs.sorted.vcf.gz"

rule update_vcf:
    input:
        len="genome/genome_contigs_len_cumsum.txt",
        vcf="filtered/all.vcf.gz",
    output:
        upd= "updated/{supercontig}.updated.vcf.gz",
    shell:
        r"""
        python 3.7 scripts/update_genomic_reg.py -len {input.len} \
            -vcf {input.vcf} -scaf {wildcards.supercontig}
        """

rule list_updated: 
    input:
        expand("updated/{supercontig}.updated.vcf.gz", supercontig= supercontigs),
    output:
        "updated/all_supercontigs.sorted.vcf.gz",
    shell:
        r"""
        ls {input} > {output}
        """
```

Comment: This suggestion did not really work because of this line
`supercontigs= get_scontigs_names()` but I solved the problem by splitting the rule into two (see below).

Comment: @SamPer - Indeed, code edited according to your answer below.