# Using checkpoints with snakemake gives each instance of a rule all input files

Tags: snakemake

I've recently come across `checkpoints` in snakemake and realized they will work perfectly with what I am trying to do. I've been able to implement the workflow [listed here](https://evodify.com/snakemake-checkpoint-tutorial/). I also found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853194/parallelise-output-of-input-function-in-snakemake), but can't quite make sense of it or how I might make it work for what I am doing

The rules I am working with are as follows:

```
def ReturnBarcodeFolderNames():
    path = config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/"
    return_direc = []
    for root, directory, files in os.walk(path):
        for direc in directory:
            return_direc.append(direc)
    return return_direc


rule all:
    input:
        expand(config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/{folder}.merged.fastq", folder=ReturnBarcodeFolderNames())


checkpoint barcode:
    input:
        expand(config['results_folder'] + "Basecall/{fast5_files}", fast5_files=FAST5_FILES)
    output:
        temp(directory(config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/.tempOutput/"))
    shell:
        "guppy_barcoder "
        "--input_path {input} "
        "--save_path {output} "
        "--barcode_kits EXP-PBC096 "
        "--recursive"

def aggregate_barcode_folders(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.barcode.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    folder_names = []
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(checkpoint_output):
        for direc in directories:
            folder_names.append(direc)

    return expand(config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/.tempOutput/{folder}", folder=folder_names)

rule merge:
    input:
        aggregate_barcode_folders
    output:
        config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/{folder}.merged.fastq"
    shell:
         "echo {input}"
```

The `rule barcode` and `def aggregate_barcode_folders` work as expected, but when `rule merge` is reached, every input folder is being passed to each instance of the rule. This results in something like the following:

```
rule merge:
    input: /Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode81, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode28, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode17, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode10, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode26, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode21, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode42, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode89, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode45, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode20, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode18, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode27, 
/Results/Barcode/.tempOutput/barcode11, 
.
.
.
.
.
    output: /Results/Barcode/barcode75.merged.fastq
    jobid: 82
    wildcards: folder=barcode75
```

The same exact input is needed for each job of `rule merge`, which amounts to about 80 instances. But, the `wildcards` portion in each job is different for each folder. How can I use this as input for each instance of my `rule merge`, instead of passing the entire list received from `def aggregate_barcode_folders`?

I feel there may be something amiss with the input from `rule all`, but I'm not 100% sure what the problem may be.

As a note, I know snakemake will throw an error stating that it is waiting for output files from `rule merge`, as I am not doing anything with the output other than printing it to the screen.

## **EDIT**

I've decided to go against checkpoints for now, and instead opt for the following. To make things more clear, the goal for this pipeline is as follows: I am attempting to merge fastq files from an output folder into one file, with the input files having a variable number of files (1 to about 3 per folder, but I won't know how many). The structure of the input is as follows

**INPUT**

```
|-- Results
    |-- FolderA
        |-- barcode01
            |-- file1.fastq
        |-- barcode02
            |-- file1.fastq
            |-- file2.fastq
        |-- barcode03
            |-- file1.fastq
    |-- FolderB
        |-- barcode01
            |-- file1.fastq
        |-- barcode02
            |-- file1.fastq
            |-- file2.fastq
        |-- barcode03
            |-- file1.fastq
    |-- FolderC
        |-- barcode01
            |-- file1.fastq
            |-- file2.fastq
        |-- barcode02
            |-- file1.fastq
        |-- barcode03
            |-- file1.fastq
            |-- file2.fastq
```

**OUTPUT**
I would like to turn that output resembling something such as:

```
|-- Results
    |-- barcode01.merged.fastq
    |-- barcode02.merged.fastq
    |-- barcode03.merged.fastq
```

The output files would contain data from all `file#.fastq` from its respective barcode folder, from folder `A`, `B`, and `C`.

I've been able to get (I think) further than I was before, but snakemake is throwing an error that says `Missing input files for rule basecall: /Users/joshl/PycharmProjects/ARS/Results/DataFiles/fast5/FAL03879_67a0761e_1055/ barcode72.fast5`. My code relevant code is here:

**CODE**

```py
configfile: "config.yaml"
FAST5_FILES = glob_wildcards(config['results_folder'] + "DataFiles/fast5/{fast5_files}.fast5").fast5_files

def return_fast5_folder_names():
    path = config['results_folder'] + "Basecall/"
    fast5_folder_names = []
    for item in os.scandir(path):
        if Path(item).is_dir():
            fast5_folder_names.append(item.name)

    return fast5_folder_names

def return_barcode_folder_names():
    path = config['results_folder'] + ".barcodeTempOutput"
    fast5_folder_names = []
    collated_barcode_folder_names = []

    for item in os.scandir(path):
        if Path(item).is_dir():
            full_item_path = os.path.join(path, item.name)
            fast5_folder_names.append(full_item_path)

    index = 0
    for item in fast5_folder_names:
        collated_barcode_folder_names.append([])
        for folder in os.scandir(item):
            if Path(folder).is_dir():
                collated_barcode_folder_names[index].append(folder.name)
        index += 1

    return collated_barcode_folder_names


rule all:
    input:
        # basecall
        expand(config['results_folder'] + "Basecall/{fast5_file}", fast5_file=FAST5_FILES),

         # barcode
        expand(config['results_folder'] + ".barcodeTempOutput/{fast5_folders}", fast5_folders=return_fast5_folder_names()),

        # merge files
        expand(config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/{barcode_numbers}.merged.fastq", barcode_numbers=return_barcode_folder_names())

rule basecall:
    input:
         config['results_folder'] + "DataFiles/fast5/{fast5_file}.fast5"
    output:
        directory(config['results_folder'] + "Basecall/{fast5_file}")
    shell:
         r"""
         guppy_basecaller \
         --input_path {input} \
         --save_path {output} \
         --quiet \
         --config dna_r9.4.1_450bps_fast.cfg \
         --num_callers 2 \
         --cpu_threads_per_caller 6
         """

rule barcode:
    input:
        config['results_folder'] + "Basecall/{fast5_folders}"
    output:
        directory(config['results_folder'] + ".barcodeTempOutput/{fast5_folders}")
    threads: 12
    shell:
         r"""
         for item in {input}; do
                guppy_barcoder \
                --input_path $item \
                --save_path {output} \
                --barcode_kits EXP-PBC096 \
                --recursive
         done         
         """

rule merge_files:
    input:
        expand(config['results_folder'] + ".barcodeTempOutput/" + "{fast5_folder}/{barcode_numbers}",
               fast5_folder=glob_wildcards(config['results_folder'] + ".barcodeTempOutput/{fast5_folders}/{barcode_numbers}/{fastq_files}.fastq").fast5_folders,
               barcode_numbers=glob_wildcards(config['results_folder'] +".barcodeTempOutput/{fast5_folders}/{barcode_numbers}/{fastq_files}.fastq").barcode_numbers)
    output:
        config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/{barcode_numbers}.merged.fastq"
    shell:
        r"""
        echo "Hello world"
        echo {input}
        """
```

Under `rule all`, if I comment out the line that corresponds to merge files, there is no error

Comment: I've figured out I can do `"echo {wildcards.folder}"` in the `shell` portion under `rule merge`, but I still have every input folder needed for ~80 instances of the merge rule. If I can't fix this portion its okay, but it would be a lot cleaner looking if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fully understanding what you mean, but I think the problem lies indeed in the input for `rule all`. I currently also do not have access to a computer (I'm on my phone right now), so I can not make a real example.. Probably what you want to do is change `ReturnBarcodeFolderNames` to use a checkpoint. I guess only after `rule barcode` you actually know what you want as final output.

```
def ReturnBarcodeFolderNames(wildcards):
    # the wildcard here makes sure that barcode is executed first
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.barcode.get().output[0]
    
    folder_names = []
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(checkpoint_output):
        for direc in directories:
            folder_names.append(direc)

    return expand(config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/{folder}.merged.fastq", folder=folder_names)


rule all:
    input:
        ReturnBarcodeFolderNames


rule merge:
    input:
        config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/.tempOutput/{folder}"
    output:
        config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/{folder}.merged.fastq"
    shell:
         "echo {input}"
```

Obviously `ReturnBarcodeFolderNames` does not work in its current form. However, the idea is that you check what you want as final output in `rule all` after `rule barcode` has been executed. Rule merge then does not have to use the checkpoint, as its input and output can be clearly defined.

I hope this helps :), but maybe I have been addressing something else than your problem. It wasn't completely clear to me from the question unfortunately.

---

**edit**

Here is a stripped down version of the code, but it should be easy to implement the last parts now. It works for the folder structure you gave in the example:

```
import os
import glob


def get_merged_barcodes(wildcards):
    tmpdir = checkpoints.barcode.get(**wildcards).output[0]  # this forces the checkpoint to be executed before we continue
    barcodes = set()  # a set is like a list, but only stores unique values
    for folder in os.listdir(tmpdir):
        for barcode in os.listdir(tmpdir + "/" + folder):
            barcodes.add(barcode)

    mergedfiles = ["results/" + barcode + ".merged.fastq" for barcode in barcodes]
    return mergedfiles
    

rule all:
    input:
        get_merged_barcodes


checkpoint barcode:
    input:
        rules.basecall.output
    output:
        directory("results")
    shell:
        """
        stuff
        """


def get_merged_input(wildcards):
    return glob.glob(f"results/**/{wildcards.barcode}/*.fastq")



rule merge_files:
    input:
        get_merged_input
    output:
        "results/{barcode}.merged.fastq"
    shell:
        """
        echo {input}
        """
```

Basically what you did in the original question was almost working!

Comment: Thank you for this, I think it's making some sense. I was able to implement it, but how do I incorporate the wildcard from `ReturnBarcodeFolderNames` into my `rule all` input? Do I need to use the `expand()` function within `rule all: input:`? I would appreciate a little more help, if you could give it; I'm still a bit lost

Comment: @JoshLoecker, what do you mean, I do not understand. What wildcard are you talking about? You do not have to use the variable if you dont use it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made myself more clear. I am unable to get `rule merge` to run, which I think is because its output is not listed in `rule all`. How do I incorporate the `config['results_folder'] + "Barcode/**{folder}**.merged.fasatq"` portion into my `rule all`?

Comment: @JoshLoecker I changed ReturnBarcodeFolderNames to use the logic of the previous code. I guess this should work. If not, please edit your question to be more clear in what you want to achieve, what your input(files) are, what your outputfiles and intermediate files are :)

Comment: I've updated my question to include input format, output format, and the code I'm currently using. I've moved away from checkpoints, just so you know. Maybe I should ask this as a separate question now?

Comment: @JoshLoecker, thanks for expanding your question, it is clear now. You do need checkpoints for this I believe. I will try to make a working example :)

Comment: Thank you!  I do believe the problem is in the `barcode` rule. I have modified the wildcard used there and the error changes with the wildcard name.

Comment: I'm getting an error that says `Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'fast5_file'` on the `checkpoint barcode` portion

Comment: @JoshLoecker, my bad. Just change the input/output of the checkpoint barcode to what you had before.

Comment: Ahh that works! Thank you so much for your patience (and hand-holding) along the way, it really means a lot :) :)

Comment: @JoshLoecker No problem! I'm happy we finally got it working :). We all need some hand holding from time to time. As a little tip, try to ask questions a bit clearer next time. It is difficult and time consuming, but makes it much easier in solving it for the other side ;)

Comment: Sorry Maarten, I had clicked the wrong button to move to chat. However, I was working with this yesterday and today and I was wondering if you would be able to help me convert this to be able to use the `{fast5_file}` wildcard under `checkpoint barcode`? I have been unable to get this to work

Comment: Sure, what do you mean? As long as input and output have the same wildcard you should be able to use the wildcard.

Comment: @JoshLoecker p.s. I went on holidays so I might be slow to respond

Comment: Okay, thank you! So currently, when running the workflow when using the your most recent edit and placing `{fast5_file}` as an output for `rule barcode`, I get an error that says that `WorkflowError: Missing wildcard values for fast5_files`, and it points me to line 31, which is where `rule all` is at

Comment: @JoshLoecker, My guess would be that's because rule all uses the input function. This inputfunction requires the checkpoint to be executed. The checkpoint requires the wildcard fast5_file. However you do not know the wildcard fast5_file until after execution. Kind of chicken and egg, impossible to solve. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct. I'll have to figure out a way to try to work around this